# Group the attributes of the objects in the array

Tags: python, algorithm, structure

In an array, the orderly storage of some objects, each object has a name is the "group" attribute,How to group objects by "group" attribute,encountered group value is 0 as the same group, until encountered group is other value , At last Get a dictionary

```
source = [ {'serial':'1','group':'0'}, {'serial':'2','group':'20'}, 
           {'serial':'3','group':'0'}, {'serial':'4','group':'0'}, 
           {'serial':'6','group':'33'}, {'serial':'7','group':'0'}, 
           {'serial':'8','group':'0'}, {'serial':'8','group':'18'} ]
```

I expect this result  is

```
Result = { '20':[ 
             {'serial':'2','group':'20'}, 
             {'serial':'3','group':'0'}, 
             {'serial':'4','group':'0'} ], 
          '33':[ 
             {'serial':'6','group':'33'}, 
             {'serial':'7','group':'0'}, 
             {'serial':'8','group':'0'} ], 
          '18':[ {'serial':'8','group':'18'} ] 
        }
```

Comment: If I did not make it clear, please look at the picture

Comment: source = [
 {'serial':'1','group':'0'},
 {'serial':'2','group':'20'},
 {'serial':'3','group':'0'},
 {'serial':'4','group':'0'},
 {'serial':'6','group':'33'},
 {'serial':'7','group':'0'},
 {'serial':'8','group':'0'},
 {'serial':'8','group':'18'}
 ]

Comment: IWantResult = {
 '20':[
    {'serial':'2','group':'20'},
    {'serial':'3','group':'0'},
    {'serial':'4','group':'0'}
   ],
 '33':[
       {'serial':'6','group':'33'},
    {'serial':'7','group':'0'},
    {'serial':'8','group':'0'}
   ]
 '18':[
    {'serial':'8','group':'18'}
   ]
}

Comment: No, **you must post the code in the question itself as formatted text**. Do not reference pictures, or even worse - links to pictures.

Comment: Ok thanks I have sent the code up

Comment: If "group" == 0,It will be assigned to a group of "group" ! = 0 above

Comment: in your source, the first value of group is 0, where should it go ?

Comment: It is not in the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work as you expect, using OrderedDict to keep the order of source input :

```
from collections import OrderedDict
result = OrderedDict()
group = None

for dic in source:
    if dic['group'] == '0':
        if group:
            result[group].append(dic)

    elif dic['group'] in result:
        result[dic['group']].append(dic)
    else:
        group = dic['group']
        result[dic['group']] = [dic]

>>> OrderedDict([('20',
              [{'group': '20', 'serial': '2'},
               {'group': '0', 'serial': '3'},
               {'group': '0', 'serial': '4'}]),
             ('33',
              [{'group': '33', 'serial': '6'},
               {'group': '0', 'serial': '7'},
               {'group': '0', 'serial': '8'}]),
             ('18', [{'group': '18', 'serial': '8'}])])
```

Comment: Ah ha! Your method is very effective, this problem is finally resolved
Thanks